# Extract complete argument and function name(s) from the Expression, (standard mathematical functions only) MAPLE

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

For expressions like

```
a1 := sin(1+a/b);
a2 := log(1+ a*b);
a3 := abs(a^2+b);
```

how can I get expressions of respective functions. For example

```
someCommand(a1)  # should get an output 1+a/b
someCommand(a2)  # should get an output 1+a*b
someCommand(a3)  # should get an output a^2+b
```

I have tried to get related topics from maple documentation but unfortunately am not able to get exactly.

edited: Also how is it possible to get list (in sequence)of functions used

let

```
a :=sin(log(abs(a+b)));# functions can be of more than two
someCommand(a) # have to return [{sin, log, abs}, a+b]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your followup comment to another Answer you gave the further example of `sin(log(abs(a+b)))`.  I suspect that you want to be able to slice and dice even more complicated examples.

You haven't really told use what your final goal is. Perhaps you're trying to build an *expression tree*. Or perhaps you're evenutally planning on doing something else with this analysis. It'd *really* help if you told us the final goal.

Having said that, the following might be of some use to you.

```
restart;

ee := "sin(log(abs(a+b))) + sin(s+t) + abs(log(v+w))":

P:=InertForm:-Parse(ee):

lprint(P);


 `%+`(%sin(%log(%abs(`%+`(a,b)))),%sin(`%+`(s,t)),
      %abs(%log(`%+`(v,w))))
```

It may be that the above inert form is something you can work with, for whatever your goal might be.

```
indets(P, specfunc(name,`%+`));

            {a %+ b, s %+ t, v %+ w}

indets(P, specfunc(anything,%abs));

       {%abs(a %+ b), %abs(%log(v %+ w))}

indets(P, specfunc(specfunc(name,`%+`),%abs));

                {%abs(a %+ b)}

indets(P, specfunc(specfunc(name,`%+`),%log));

                {%log(v %+ w)}
```

Using a routine limke from my earlier Answer,

```
W := (ee,nm) -> [op(map(`[]`@op,indets(ee,':-specfunc'(nm))))]:

W( indets(P, specfunc(specfunc(name,`%+`),%log)), `%+` );

                   [[v, w]]

W( indets(P, specfunc(specfunc(name,`%+`),%sin)), `%+` );

                   [[s, t]]

W( indets(P, specfunc(specfunc(name,`%+`),%abs)), `%+` );

                   [[a, b]]
```

There are other ways to get those last results (using something like `W` on an actual expression and not its inert form, say). I'm just trying to show you how you can do a bit more with it all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `op()` command, which breaks down expressions into their operands. For instance:

```
f := sin(1+a/b);
g := op(0,f); # sin
h := op(1,f); # 1+a/b
```

Comment: This explanation can handle one function at a time. what if the expression in complx like --> sin(log(abs(a+b)))?

Comment: You continue to ignore the good advice given by others in a recent related question (one of several) in this theme. Stop asking about subtasks of a methodology that you've cooked up for some broader, *as-yet-unstated*, purpose. Write a single Question of your *final* goal, with *proper details* and as complicated an example as represents the *full* functionality you hope to achieve. You may well find that there is a better overall approach, and it'd be a better use of everyone's time. Changing your questions by piecemeal augmentation of the examples wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 3):

That's not complicated to construct. (More thoughts on that, below...)

```
restart;

W := (ee,nm::name) -> [op(map(`[]`@op,indets(ee,':-specfunc'(nm))))]:
```

And now to test it,

```
a1 := sin(1+a/b):
a2 := log(1+ a*b):
a3 := abs(a^2+b):

W( a1, sin );
                       [[    a]]
                       [[1 + -]]
                       [[    b]]

W( a2, ln );
                      [[a b + 1]]

W( a3, abs );
                       [[ 2    ]]
                       [[a  + b]]
```

Now a slightly longer example,

```
foo := cos(1+a/b)/abs(a^2+b)
       +log(1+ a*b)*cos(s-v)
       +sin(c+d/r);

              /    a\                                      
           cos|1 + -|                                      
              \    b/                               /    d\
    foo := ---------- + ln(a b + 1) cos(s - v) + sin|c + -|
            | 2    |                                \    r/
            |a  + b|                                       

W( foo, sin );
                       [[    d]]
                       [[c + -]]
                       [[    r]]

W( foo, cos );
                   [[    a]         ]
                   [[1 + -], [s - v]]
                   [[    b]         ]

W( foo, abs );
                       [[ 2    ]]
                       [[a  + b]]

W( foo, ln );
                      [[a b + 1]]
```

With no other context to judge by, I personally prefer to have the items above be returned within lists, to be able to handle them later more easily.

But it looks even simpler, if one leaves out the encapsulating lists,

```
Y := (ee,nm::name) -> op(map(op,indets(ee,':-specfunc'(nm)))):

Y( foo, cos );

                          a       
                      1 + -, s - v
                          b
```

Now a few opinions. The reason that there is no dedicated command for doing *precisely* this is because there are so very many tasks in a similar vein. A programming language that is crammed full of hundreds of distinct commands to do too similar things can be awkward (or worse) to use.

To use Maple effectively it helps to learn the basic building blocks very well. Those include at least things like,

```
op, map, map[n], zip, select, remove, selectremove,
table, indices, entries, type, indets, subsindets,
normal, radnormal, simplify, evalc, evala, rationalize
```

Comment: I should be more clear about why I prefer wrapping the individual results in square brackets (ie. as lists). Calls to `abs`, `arctan`, etc, can take more than one argument. Wrapping in lists prevent multiple results from multiple instances of the same "function" from being muddled together with loss of the precise information.