# convert a set to expression Maple/ Change prefix to In-fix expression

Tags: symbolic-math, maple

How to convert the below set to expression

```
Expression := {{a°b}, {a°x°y}} # ° can be any operator
```

required output as

```
result := {a°b, a°x°y}  #required output
```

I have tried to convert using convert function like below,

```
asString := convert(Expression, string);
with(StringTools):
asString :=Remove("{}", asString)

result := InertForm:-Parse(asString);
```

but my output is in the order of Pre-fix expression.

result := {"`&deg;`(a,b), `&deg;`(`&deg;`(a,x),y)"}

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
restart;

foo := {{a/b}, {a+x*y}}:

result := map(op, foo):

lprint(result);
  {a/b, x*y+a}
```

There is no guarantee that the resulting set will have its entries appearing in the same order as the original set of sets. And hence using sets for this general kind of thing is never going to work properly.

That's why I used nested *lists* instead of nested *sets*, in my answers to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420940/extract-complete-expression-and-functions-name-from-the-standard-function-mapl) of your many questions on this theme last week. Your current Question indicates that you're not following my advice.